# how to select a row in a kendogrid using a string as parameter

Tags: grid, kendo-grid

I need help about select a row in a kendoGrid.

I have a simple kendoGrid with selection enabled, and when i click on a button in a webpage, i have to use a string (for example "cod001") for selecting a row in my kendogrid by a column....

for example:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.select("??????????");//here i sould select a row where the unique value is "cod001" in a defined column
```

hope someone can help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find an alternative solution, without each functions...
i'll post my solution, and hope can help somoeone with my same issues!!!

```
var g = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var selectedRow = g.select();
var index = selectedRow.index();
```

... and then...

```
            var ddl = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            ddl.select("tr:eq(" + index  + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a loop on each line of your grid to check what the column your looking for is and then select it.

```
var linesToSelect = [];
$.each($('.k-grid-content tbody').children(), function(index, line){
    // column is the column's value you want to test
    if ($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(line).column == "cod001") 
        linesToSelect.push(line);
});
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").select(linesToSelect);
```

This is not a perfect solution since you do a loop on every rows of your grid, but it should help until you find a better solution!